# How can I transfer the moment.js breakpoints into a php formular?

Tags: php, momentjs

I am using moment.js

```js
var deadline = '25/01/2018'
var days = moment(deadline, "DD/MM/YYYY").fromNow();
console.log(days)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

I want to rebuild this with php:

```
$today = $now->format('Y-m-d'); 
$deadline = "2018-01-25 00:00:00";
$date1=date_create($today);
$date2=date_create($deadline);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$days = $diff->days;
```

The problem is, that I cannot figure out any logical formular for the breakpoints... So I need to build it by hand:

```
if($days >=26){
     echo "in a month";       

}
 if($days >=47){
     echo "in 2 months";     

}
 if($days >=83){
     echo "in 3 months";   

}
 if($days >=108){
    $ echo "in 4 months";     

}
 if($days >=137){
    echo "in 5 months";   
}
 if($days >=167){
     echo "in 6 months";      
}
```

...

I just wonder if you can recognize a logic behind the breakpoints that I can put into a formular?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be much simpler and convenient for you to use [fightbulc/moment](https://packagist.org/packages/fightbulc/moment) package (that is close analog of moment.js) instead of re-inventing the wheel.